# is it possible to find the canvas shape clicked in a mouse button press event in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a Tkinter canvas and bound a mouse button press event to it.

I was wondering if I could figure out on what specific shape a user clicked when bound to a canvas:

```
def callback(event):
    pass

canvas = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
canvas.create_rectangle(10,50,40,90, tags="tile")
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
```

I know I can bind it to the the rectangle, the problem is that there might be a another shape overlaying the rectangle and then the click event doesn't work anymore.

I was thinking of using the `find_overlapping` method:

```
def callback(event):
     canvas.find_overlapping(event.x, event.y,event.x, event.y)
```

but was wondering if there is an easier way?

Comment: Does the suggested method work? It seems find by me. Also maybe `find_enclosed`

Comment: `find_enclosed` does not work bc the shape has to be inside the rectangle created by the points. `find_overlapping` works, i was hoping there is an easier way though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special item tag `current` to refer to the object under the cursor. According to the official documentation:

> The tag **current** is managed automatically by Tk; it applies to the *current item*, which is the topmost item whose drawn area covers the position of the mouse cursor (different item types interpret this in varying ways; see the individual item type documentation for details). If the mouse is not in the canvas widget or is not over an item, then no item has the **current** tag.

Here is a simple example. It draws a bunch of colored rectangles, and then sets the color to white when you click on them.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def click_handler(event):
    event.widget.itemconfigure("current", fill="white")

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="bisque", width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.bind("<1>", click_handler)
for i in range(100):
    x = random.randint(0, 350)
    y = random.randint(0, 350)
    color = random.choice(("red", "orange", "green", "blue"))
    width = random.randint(25, 50)
    height = random.randint(25, 50)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+width, y+height, fill=color)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]